# Как установить библиотеку Vreen в Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Как установить библиотеку Vreen в Qt?
Официальная инструкция по установке для ОС Linux, а у меня стоит Windows.
Очень прошу, кто может скинуть инструкцию по установке Vreen для ОС Windows (компилятор Visual Studio)